# When should I create factory or VM in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, loose-coupling, angular-factory

This is how my angular app looks like.

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("app")
    .controller("custCtrl", custCtrl);

custCtrl.$inject = ['dataService','custFactory'];

/* @ngInject */
function custCtrl(dataService, custFactory) {
    var vm = this;
    //line##
    vm.customer= custFactory.Create('customer');

    GetCustomers();
    function GetCustomers() {

        dataService.read().then(function (data) {
                vm.customer = data.fields;
            }
        });

    }

    return vm;
}
})();
```

Factory Method

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.factory')
    .factory('custFactory', custFactory);

custFactory.$inject = ['$q'];

/* @ngInject */
function custFactory($q) {
    var _create = function (type) {

        var obj = {};

        switch (type.toString().toLowerCase()) {
            case "customer":
                obj = new Customer();
                break;
            default:
                obj = null;
        }

        return obj;
    }

    return {
        Create: _create
    };
}
})();
```

View Model

```
 function Customer()
 {

var dto = this;

dto.Customer = {
  "Name" : "",
  "Gender" : "", // & so on
}

 return dto;
}
```

If you check my above `custCtrl` on //line##, I am calling factory method to instantiate customer object as below.

```
vm.customer= custFactory.Create('customer');
```

But if I **don't** create a customer VM & factory and simple assign an empty string as below.

```
        vm.customer= {};
```

Still its working with no issue.

> So my question why should I create a VM & factory?? What is its
>   benefit??

Comment: You are using `var vm = this;` just to represent the binding scope and remove injection of `$scope` into your controller. In general case you are decorating `vm` with the properties that should be data-bindable to the view. I don't understand why do you need the code on the line `//line##` if you then overwrite the `vm.customer` with `data.fields` in `GetCustomers()` method.

Answer (score 1):

the controller alias is suitable when you have nested controllers,

while the factory or services are suitable to share data between different controllers.

For example it's useful to have your mehtod *CreateCustomer* if you use it from different controllers. Since you don't store data in it, it would be better to use a *service* instead. Anyway it allows you to save code.

**EXAMPLE**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.factory("myFactory", function(){
    var private = {
        users: {}
    };
    var data = {
        getUser: function(id){
             return private.users[id];
        },
        createUser: function(id){
            private.users[id] = someData;
            return private.currentUser;
        }
    };

    return data;
});


app.controller("myC1", ["myFactory", function(myFactory){

     $scope.user = myFactory.createUser(1);

}]);


app.controller("myC2", ["myFactory", function(myFactory){

     $scope.user = myFactory.getUser(1);

}]);
```

As you see the two controllers can access the same data

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS patterns and best practices involve following the MV(whatever) pattern and designing/implementing modular components with high cohesion and low coupling. That way you can easily modify one piece of code without having to make changes in another piece of code.

Typically a factory or service is used as the layer of client-side code that interacts with a RESTful API or some sort of server-side code. Typically that is the only function of the factory. That way you can inject the factory into *any* controller that needs to use the factory's functions. When you need to modify how you call your API, you only need to make a change in the factory instead of every single controller that would use that function.

Similarly with the view model object you have created, you only need to make changes in one place. Imagine having five different controllers that all need to use a `Customer` object. Now you decide you want to remove the `Name` field and replace it with `FirstName` and `LastName`. Would you want to go through all your controllers and make that change, or would you want to just change the view model?

To give you the short answer. There's nothing *functionally* wrong with not creating a view model or a factory/service. From an architectural or design perspective, it makes tons of sense to have a strong separation of concerns in your application. Therefore, it makes sense to use a factory for data access and a view model for your data objects.

Try imagining your application growing to have hundreds of controllers/views and dozens of factories or services. It would be a huge pain to maintain that application if you didn't have these patterns and best practices implemented from the beginning of development.

Comment: Thanks!! the thing that is confusing me is why do I need //line## if  then overwrite the vm.customer with data.fields in GetCustomers() method